# Combining `where` and `like` statements by using the CI activerecords

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

To cut a long story short: Is it possible and if it is - how can I build a query that looks somewhat like this one

```
SELECT * FROM a
    WHERE row = 1 AND 
    (other_row LIKE '%..%' OR another_row LIKE '%..%')
```

Basically I cann't come up / find a solution to this problem. I just cann't seem to figure how to add the brackets to the activerecords query. Is that even possible?

My current code:

```
$data = $this->where('row', 1)
    ->like('another_row', '...')        
    ->or_where('row', 1)
    ->like('other_row', $search)                
    ->get('a')
    ->result();
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM (`a`) WHERE `row` = 1 OR `row` = 1 AND `another_row` LIKE '%...%' AND other_row` LIKE '%...%'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this.

```
   $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('a')
            ->where('row',1)
            ->where("(other_row LIKE '%%' OR another_row LIKE '%%' )")
            ->get();


    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        //do sth.
    }
```

You can write custom query string (from active record class)

```
 Custom string:
 You can write your own clauses manually:

 $where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";

 $this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also having problem with `or_where` so i simply make my custom query like

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `a` WHERE `row`=1 AND (CONDITION1 OR CONDITION2)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `a`
WHERE row = '1' AND 
(other_row LIKE '%" . $value . "%' OR another_row LIKE '%" . $value . "%')";
 $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this:

```
    $this->db->where("row = 1 AND 
        (other_row LIKE '%..%' OR another_row LIKE '%..%')");
$this->db->get('a');
```

It's how you can write custom WHERE in CI. If it is not what u r looking for, feel free to explain

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before');
```

It will produce:

```
WHERE `title` LIKE '%match' ESCAPE '!'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('salary_range_min >= ',$salarymin)
$this->db->where('salary_range_max <= ',$salarymax)
$this->db->where('job_title like '.$title.'% or skill like %'.$title.'%');
// OR */
$this->db->where('job_title like '.$title.'% or skill like %'.$title.'%',FALSE);
// OR */
$this->db->where('job_title like '.$title.'% or skill like %'.$title.'%',NULL);
```

Try this out