# where clause not working with like query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a search query and when I search all like keywords work properly the records are showing with the matched criteria, but the problem is that where clause in not working.

```
$position = $this->session->set_userdata('position', $this->input->post('position'));
$adress_all = explode(",", $this->session->userdata('address'));
$this->db->like('address', $adress_all[0]);
$this->db->or_like('game', $this->session->userdata('skills'));
$this->db->or_like('gender', $this->session->userdata('coach'));
$this->db->or_like('Positions', $this->session->userdata('position'));
$this->db->where('type', 'private');//all other type coaches is also showing up
$sql = $this->db->get('coach');
```

Comment: please add your query output by using this `echo $this->db->last_query()`

Comment: `$this->db->like()` is converted to `where  column LIKE 'your_string'` clause so you do not need to add another where

Comment: so i just need records to be shown private coaches only so that is why I am using where clause

Comment: @Raj 
SELECT * FROM `coach` WHERE `type` = 'private' AND `address` LIKE '%2207 Broadway%' ESCAPE '!' OR `game` LIKE '%Basketball%' ESCAPE '!' OR `gender` LIKE '%Male%' ESCAPE '!' OR `Positions` LIKE '%Guard%' ESCAPE '!'

Comment: So you have the `OR` query needed within a bracket

Comment: yes please check my question

Comment: @MarkAlan : so you want `type = 'private' and address will match any of the critarea`, right ?

Comment: yes every like clause be searched from only private records as there are 2 types of coaches private and college so user can only get search results for private coaches in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining \`where\` and \`like\` statements by using the CI activerecords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492058/combining-where-and-like-statements-by-using-the-ci-activerecords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below things.

```
$this->db->where('type', 'private');//all other type coaches is also showing up
$this->db->where("(address LIKE '%". $adress_all[0]."%' OR game LIKE '%".$this->session->userdata('skills')."%' OR gender LIKE '%".$this->session->userdata('coach')."%' OR positions LIKE '%".$this->session->userdata('position')."%')",null,false);
$sql = $this->db->get('coach');
```

Comment: Your rocks ! thumbs up for you :)

Comment: You may write like this as it is directly a sql query:
`$this->db->where("type like 'private' AND ( address like % ....OR .....OR ...so on...)");`

however, problem solved... :)

Comment: does using 'like' as statement between object oriented query, breaks any rule of object oriented query? I mean, should it be specifically used with $this->db->like() or as @Raj has done it, will have no issues?

Comment: I don't think it will break any rules because we are generating query from active records so in case if we switch to other database in future than we don't need to change the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Grouping LIKE` of codeigniter

```
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->like('address', $adress_all[0]);
$this->db->or_like('game', $this->session->userdata('skills'));
$this->db->or_like('gender', $this->session->userdata('coach'));
$this->db->or_like('Positions', $this->session->userdata('position'));
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->where('type', 'private');
$sql = $this->db->get('coach');
```

Hope this works(need to test on your DB)

[See Doc](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1881)

Comment: No results found this is the output of the query 
SELECT * FROM `coach` WHERE `address` LIKE '%2207 Broadway%' ESCAPE '!' AND ( `game` LIKE '%Basketball%' ESCAPE '!' OR `gender` LIKE '%Male%' ESCAPE '!' OR `Positions` LIKE '%Guard%' ESCAPE '!' ) AND `type` = 'private' game and position is marched but not giving back the result

Comment: updated. you need to put the address within the group column