# select with like convert number in html entities

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making use of LIKE with codeigniter, I have already tried using the framework standard:

```
$ this->db->or_like("field", $string);
```

But I have had problems when the user types for example: 40077

As you are using LIKE, "%" is added before the search string, this value is converted to "@ 077" because "% 40" is HTML entities. "

To "solve", I stopped using the framework conventions and made the query normally, as follows:

```
$ sql. = "OR field LIKE '" .urlencode ("%". $string. "%"). "' ESCAPE '!' ";
```

Resolved partially, because when the searched content is text and has space, the "+" is added in place of the space. But for the searches with numbers, he decided.

But it is clear that this solution is regrettable.

Can anyone share any experience to help me solve the problem?

Thank you all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand the problem. Why are you using `urlencode()` in a query?? That's obviously going to alter the data and you _will_ get unexpected results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining \`where\` and \`like\` statements by using the CI activerecords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492058/combining-where-and-like-statements-by-using-the-ci-activerecords)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

> $this->db->or_like("field", htmlspecialchars($string));